# Swift how to prevent multiple NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have been making a stopwatch.

and start, stop, and pause action work great.

However, When I click start action double times which is

```
time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

this action start again and the time run faster!

how do i prevent the action?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Check when you set time that it hasn't already been set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a variable on the top of your class:

```
 var timer = NSTimer()
```

then you assign this timer variable in your start button, like so:

```
@IBAction func startTimerButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
   time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

whenever you want to stop this timer, you need to invalidate it, like so:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

If you want to click the start button two more time, you need to invalidate it first before schedule it:

```
@IBAction func startTimerButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
       timer.invalidate()
       time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes I did the same. However, startTimerButtonTapped function is able to activate multiple times. I want to prevent it.

Comment: Did you invalidate() it like I said?

Comment: Oh I didn't see timer.invalidate() in startTimerButtonTapped function!!! Thanks It works great!

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple answer!!!

However, The answer above is simpler than an answer I found.

What I found was

I just need to declare a variable let say

```
var isStop = true
```

then when

```
Timer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()
```

run I need to put

```
isStop = false
```

and also every pause and stop action
I need to put

```
isStop = true
```

Thanks everyone for reminding me of thinking different!!